# How can I use $stateprovider to dynamically create states for each node of a tree?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

In my application users are traversing a tree that can get a little deep. Each level of the tree is populated via a rest call. The page however remains oblivious to the traversal happening inside it, so if anything happens to the page (ie refreshed or closed), the user's work is lost. I would like to maintain the state of the traversal, and I think that doing this via `$stateprovider` is the best way, but I am unsure of how.

Specifically, how can I use `$stateprovider` to dynamically resolve states? In other words, when given the url `/traversal/a/b/c`, I want to display all of `c`s children, and know that i got to `c` by going `a->b->c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is Regex Parameters explained here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters in particular the catch all path.

I tackled a similar problem recently whilst playing around with the Github API.

As per the docs you can use:

```
'/files/*path'
```

so anything after a route you define is accessible with

```
$stateParams.path
```

You could then split the path into it's parts and do what you will with it.

**Note:** Don't forget to inject $stateParams into your controller